# Derivation of the inverse of a block matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse

There is a formula for the inverse of a block matrix in terms of its blocks. I'm not gonna state the formula here as its quite elaborate.

None of my linear algebra textbooks explain how to derive this formula or why its true.

**Could you point me to a good explanation? (Or explain it youraelf if you are willing to!)**

Comment: Why it is true: you can just multiply the block matrix with the proposed inverted matrix and observe that you get the identity out. Either way, this question is more suited to math.stackexchange.

Comment: @MeesdeVries, right, but I'm looking for more of a way to derive it without first already knowing the answer.